# How to use truffle-assertions to check if a constructor will revert?

Tags: solidity, truffle, truffle-test, constructor, revert-opcode

Say I have a contract:

```
contract Reverts{
    constructor(param1){
        require(param1);
    }
}
```

If `param1` is false, the constructor should fail and revert state.

`truffle-assertions` allows me to check if an *existing* contract abstraction's function will revert using `await truffleAssertions.reverts(Reverts.someFunc());`

That doesn't apply to constructors, since they are what make the contract abstraction in the first place.

**How can I achieve this functionality with a constructor, instead of a regular function?**

In a Truffle JavaScript testing file:

```
const truffleAssertions = require("truffle-assertions");
const Reverts = artifacts.require("Reverts");
let reverts;

contract("Reverts", (accounts) => {
    it("Check that param1=false, constructor reverts.", async () =>{
        // What to do here?
    });
});
```

Comment: Use a try/catch block

Answer (score 0):

For this example contract, I used:

```
contract("Reverts", (accounts) => {
    it("Check that param1=false, constructor reverts.", async () =>{
        try{
            await Reverts.new(false);
        }
        catch{return;}
        assert.fail("Constructor does not revert when param1=false.");
    });
});
```

If the constructor reverts, the test simply returns and shows as passing. If it does not revert, then the assert statement is reached, causing an fail.

Answer (score 0):

With `@openzeppelin/test-helpers` you can do:

```
const { expectRevert } = require("@openzeppelin/test-helpers");
const Reverts = artifacts.require("Reverts");

contract("Reverts", (accounts) => {
    it("Check that param1=false, constructor reverts.", async () =>{
        await expectRevert.unspecified(Reverts.new(false));
    });
});
```

or

```
await expectRevert(Reverts.new(false), "some revert string");
```

if the require include a reason string.